# Kotlin spring boot test with variable data comparison

Tags: kotlin, spring-boot-test

I have spring boot test in Kotlin where I want to check the response of a POST request. The response contains a UUID that is generated each time, which I cannot hard code for test.

How can I avoid checking this UUID in the test but ensure the format of response is correct?

For example, my comparison looks like the following below. I'd like to confirm the key `userUUID` is there but not check its value.

```
    val response = mvc
        .perform(requestBuilder)
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().string("""{"userUUID":"DONT_CARE","status":"Completed"}"""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content().string()` does not only accept a string to check for equality, it can also accept an instance of a hamcrest matcher, e.g. the `containsString(str: String)` matcher, which you could use or provide your own implementation, that uses a regex to check if the result is correct.
See here for documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html
https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get something working by checking the individual element like, `.andExpect(content().string(containsString(""""userUUID":"1234"""")))`